# Why is volume work not a state function? Solution using total differential

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to show that volume work is not a state function by using total differential. I know that $dW=-p dV$ and I should show that this differential is not exact in order to conclude that work is not a state function. But I don't really understand how I should do this, it is quite unclear to me what I should do, because if I let $P(W, V)=1$ and $Q(W, V)=-p$, then $\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial W}=0$, so I think that the differential would be exact??

Comment: All you need to show is that, with the exception of an adiabatic process, there are an infinite number of paths connecting the same two end states (initial and final pressures and volumes) involving potentially different amounts of work. Since a state function is, by definition, independent of the path between to states, work is not a state function.

Comment: @BobD I agree with you, but I was interested in approaching this using the criterion with the exact total differential (because this is how I saw that I am expected to solve such questions by my instructor)

Comment: What is the downvote for? I am just trying to understand how to solve this questions by using the total differential, if I should add anything else, please let me now

Comment: I didn't downvote it.  Why it was, I have no idea.

Comment: @BobD thanks, I am quite new to the physics website and this is why I was afraid that I may have ommitted something. Any idea how I could solve the question the way I want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the equation for work should be written as

$$\delta W=pdV$$

While it mades sense to use the exact differential for an infinitesimal *change* in a thermodynamic property, such as volume $dV$, it makes no sense to talk about an infinitesimal "change" in work since work is not something that "changes". It is a quantity of energy that is transferred between a system and it surroundings due solely to temperature difference. That transfer can then result in a differential change in other thermodynamic properties.

Instead we should be talking about an infinitesimal "quantity" of work, by using the symbol $\delta$ to mean inexact differential. The same applies to heat $Q$. Then the differential form of the first law for a closed system is written

$$dU=\delta Q-\delta W$$

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, so I should check whether the differential form $dU=\delta Q-\delta W$ is exact or not?

Comment: @ChemistryGeek Although $\delta Q$ and $\delta W$ are individually inexact differentials, their combination results in the exact differential $dU$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, basically what I wish to show is that $\delta W$ is inexact in order to reach my conclusion, right? How would I go about this?

Comment: @ChemistryGeek I'm not sure what your instructor is looking for, but you can connect the same two end states with a constant volume process (W=0) followed by a constant pressure process where $W=p\Delta V$. Or you could reverse the two getting different values of Q and W for the same $\Delta U$,  showing that W and Q are inexact differentials.